# Failure of leibnizian notation for differentiation

Tags: calculus

In Spivak's  *Calculus*, it's given that Leibniz considered derivative not as the limit of the quotient $\bigl(f(x+h)-f(x)\bigr)/h$ but the "value" of the quotient when $h$ is an infinitely small number.

What is wrong if we consider derivative as the value of the quotient when $h$ is infinitesimally small.

Comment: Notice it's not very small, it's infinitely small.

Comment: The defining properties of the real numbers are that they're a complete, ordered, field. When you allow infinitesimals, like in the field of rational functions, you break completeness so you can't ensure the existence of certain limits.

Comment: Can u give an example where we cannot ensure the existence of certain limits.

Comment: Define infinitesimally small.

Comment: There are no infinitesimally small numbers. This may help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1991575/why-cant-the-second-fundamental-theorem-of-calculus-be-proved-in-just-two-lines/1991585#1991585

Comment: So what are epsilon and delta in limits definition?

Comment: @ARMY1729 "what are epsilon and delta...?" They are positive real numbers that are never infinitely small in that they're always bigger than $1/n$ for some positive integer $n$. There are lots of questions about understanding the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition of limits better on MSE, and other explanations online if Spivak's wasn't helpful.

Comment: In proofs about limits, $\epsilon$ is usually introduced with a statement such as "Let $\epsilon$ be a positive real number." So $\epsilon$ is just an ordinary real number.

Comment: Ok,thank u very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some sense, what mathematicians have decided to call "the real numbers" is the biggest bunch of numbers that you can do arithmetic with (including divide by nonzero numbers) in a way that works nicely with inequalities (so non-real complex numbers like $i$ aren't allowed), that does **not** have anything that's "infinitely big" (absolute value greater than any integer).

If $h$ is "infinitely small" (absolute value less than $1/n$ for any positive integer $n$) but not zero, then $1/h$ would be infinitely big, and that wouldn't be allowed for a real number. Most calculus books stick to the real numbers, and so you can't consider $h$ "infinitely small" in a book like Spivak's Calculus.

But even if you go to a [nonstandard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonstandard_calculus) book like [Elementary Calculus: An Infinitesimal Approach](https://www.math.wisc.edu/~keisler/calc.html), and allow/define nonreal numbers that can be "infinitely small", you *still* can't just say the derivative is "the value of the quotient when $h$ is infinitesimally small". It depends on the value of $h$. For example, if $f(x)=x^2$ then the quotient is $2x+h$, which has different values for different values of $h$.

So some special care must be taken with limits/derivatives whether or not you stick to the real numbers. Since the vast majority of calculus/analysis texts will be sticking to the real numbers (and for good reasons), I recommend you first learn with something like Spivak's Calculus, and then a more advanced treatment of analysis that, say, constructs the real numbers. And then you will be better prepared for reading about the unexciting reality of rephrasing the same arguments in terms of nonreal numbers that are "infinitely small", etc.