# How to treat dx in my logic of Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> After reading some of the comments and from outside help I've been made aware that my notation may have been the problem. So I'm rewriting this with a new set of questions with better notation and hopefully better understanding.

Let me start from the very beginning - Limits: $\lim_{x\to a} x$ refers to making x very small and almost $a$ but $x\ne a$

The next thing is derivation. Derivative of $f(x)$ if the limit exists refers to the new function $f'(x)$ whose each input $x$ maps to $f$ and output is the slope at that point in the $f$. In other words, the ratio of infinitely small change in $y$ when infinitely small change happens to input $x$ for every point. Mathematically,

$$
\lim_{\triangle x \to 0}\frac{f(x + \triangle x) - f(x)}{\triangle x}
$$

Indefinite integral in simpler words is just the opposite of derivative. If the derivative of $f(x)$ is $f'(x)$ then the integral of $f'(x)$ is $f(x) + C$ where $C$ can be any constant which is shown by pushing the curve up or down the slope doesn't change so all $C$ would  make the derivative same as $f'(x)$

$$
\int f'(x) = f(x) + C \ \ \ \ \&  \ \ \ \ \frac{\mathrm{d}f(x)}{\mathrm{d}x}
 = f'(x)$$

Problem come in Definate Intregal. To my understanding Definite integral is integral between fixed range $[\alpha, \beta]$ given function is continuous. This solves our problem of $C$ constant as per how it is calculated. According to Theoram:

$$
\int_\alpha^\beta f'(x) = f(\beta) - f(\alpha)
$$

which makes sense as:

$$
\begin{align}
& \ \ \ \ \ (f(\beta) + C) - (f(\alpha) + C) \\
&=  f(\beta) - f(\alpha) + (C-C)  \\
&= f(\beta) - f(\alpha)  
\end{align}
$$

> Q1. But why is it $f(\beta) - f(\alpha)$ in the first place?

Now I would also want to talk about Area. To get the Area of the curve we divide it into little rectangles with the width of $\triangle x$ which tends to 0 bur $\triangle x \ne 0$

[image]

Mathematically area will be:

$$
A() = \lim_{\triangle x \to 0} \triangle x \sum_{i=\alpha}^\beta f(x_i + (i-1)\triangle x)
$$

Since from pic $\alpha = 0.5\ \  \beta = 2.5$ the above equation is:

$$
A() = \lim_{\triangle x \to 0} \triangle x \sum_{i=0.5}^{2.5} f(x_i + (i-1)\triangle x)
$$

This equation by definition of integration is:

$$
\int_{\alpha}^\beta f(x) \triangle x
$$

Now Fundamental Theorem of Calculus says

$$
\int_{\alpha}^\beta f(x) \triangle x = F(\beta) - F(\alpha),\ \ F'(x) = f(x)
$$

> Q2 - 3:
>
> > Q2. What is the relation of Area to antiderivative function?
>
> > Q3. How one thus comes to the logic of Subtracting from a geometrical perspective, here above image.

Comment: Related, possibly helpful,possibly duplicate https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1991575/why-cant-the-second-fundamental-theorem-of-calculus-be-proved-in-just-two-lines/1991585#1991585

Comment: "Now I asume at $\infty$ it is $f(b) - (a)$" What makes you think so?

Comment: If $a$ is on the left side if its rectangle, then $b$ should also be on the left side of *its* rectangle. Then the horizontal separation is indeed $dx$. Also, the notation is terrible. You should be using $\Delta x$ instead of $dx$ because $dx$ is an infinitesimal, not a positive length.

Comment: @anne I don’t know what to do from there. I just thought it would reach it but evaluation of limit will give another answer.

Comment: @mpw in those rectangle I meant to make their width indefinitely small so that I could ignore dx. But that didn’t work out for me.

Comment: In the diagram $b = a + 2\, dx$, so as $dx \to 0$, "optimistically" I'd expect$f(b)-f(a) \to 0$ while$$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{2\,dx} = \frac{f(a+2\, dx) - f(a)}{2\, dx} \to f'(a).$$

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang how did you deduce $f(b) = f(a) + 2\ \mathrm{d}x$ Isn't the change in x axis ie. width of rectangle $\mathrm{d}x$ not little change in function itself $\mathrm{d}f(x)$ that you are referring to?

Comment: Careful: Not $f(b) = f(a) + 2\,dx$, but $f(b) = f(a + 2\,dx)$. The "$2\,dx$" is inside $f$; we have $b = a + 2\,dx$, and can substitute in $f(b)$. :)

Comment: @EthanBolker I've changed the question, I would appreciate it if you review it.

Comment: @AnneBauval I've changed the question, I would appreciate it if you review it.

Comment: @MPW I've changed the question, I would appreciate it if you review it.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I've changed the question, I would appreciate it if you review it.

Comment: I haven't carefully combed through the revised question, but it does seem that "integral" is getting used in two senses: as an antiderivative (or _indefinite integral_) and as an area (or _definite integral_). The notations are similar, but the definitions are not; that's part of why the relationship between them is ... fundamental. <> As stated the question also looks difficult to answer without writing an exposition of the proofs of the fundamental theorems. Have you read a proof of the FTCs, and can you possibly isolate what parts of the proof are hard to understand?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang No I've not yet read the proof of FTC. I'll read it today and then ask which part I don't understand.

Comment: Your notation is still wonky, especially near the bottom. Just read this : https://math.berkeley.edu/~peyam/Math1AFa10/Proof%20of%20the%20FTC.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the geometric interpretation, $\int_a^b f(z) dz$ is the total *signed* area between $f$ and the $x$-axis, where we show this intuition as the limit of Riemann sums.

Now, let's replace $b$ with a variable $x>a$ and ask what is the rate of change of the area under the curve at $x$:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^x f(z) dz = \lim_{h\to0^+} \frac{\int_a^{x+h} f(z) dz - \int_a^x f(z) dz}{h} = \lim_{h\to0^+} \frac{\int_x^{x+h} f(z) dz}{h}$$

$$=\lim_{h\to0^+} \frac1h\left[ \lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{i=0}^n f\left(x+i\frac hn\right)\frac hn\right] = \lim_{h\to0^+}\left[ \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac1n\sum_{i=0}^n f\left(x+i\frac hn\right)\right]$$

Note that the inner sum is just the mean value of the terms in the sum and the inner limit defines the following Riemann integral:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac1n\sum_{i=0}^n f\left(x+i\frac hn\right) = \frac1h \int_x^{x+h}f(z)dz$$

Which is mean value of $f$ over $[x,x+h]$

In general if $f$ is integrable over $[a,b]$ then the function $F(x):= \int_a^x f(z)dz$ is uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$ and $F(a)=0$ so $\lim_{x \to a^+} F(x)=0$

Using this, we can switch the limits in the final sum:

$$\lim_{h\to0^+}\left[ \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac1n\sum_{i=0}^n f\left(x+i\frac hn\right)\right] = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left[ \lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac1n\sum_{i=0}^n f\left(x+i\frac hn\right)\right] $$
$$= \lim_{n\to\infty}\left[ \frac1n\sum_{i=0}^n f(x)\right]=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x) = f(x)$$

So the rate of change in the area of the definite integral at $x$ is $f(x)$, as we expect.

Comment: I understood the proof but I’ve following questions: 1. What is the relation of Area to antiderivative function or How is anti derative looks like in graph to function we are infinite integrations? 2. For definite integration how does area represent its derivative. 3. Can you explain or prove or both Mean Value Theorem.